# PRFM ARM undefined reference

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm

I have an issue with ARM function : prfm ... and gcc compiler.

My code is :

```
__asm__ volatile("prfm  plil2keep, %[Addr]\n" : : [Addr] "r" (addr) : "memory");
```

and

```
__asm__ volatile("prfm  pldl1keep, %[Addr]\n" : : [Addr] "r" (addr) : "memory");
```

Unfortunately, I have the following issue : "x19" reference undefined .

But what is "x19" on this part of code.... Moreover, the value of addr comes from the parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 errors. One was because addr was not a pointer so i had to write &addr. 
And I changed %[Addr] by %0. :